# Linq to SQL Error Mapped

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;   
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace dbtst
{
        class person { public int id; public string name;}

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                DataContext db = new DataContext(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\UDMS\Documents\uhby.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
                Table<person> tble = db.GetTable<person>();

                person a = new person();
                a.id = 5;
                tble.InsertOnSubmit(a);
                person b = new person();
                a.id = 6;
                tble.InsertOnSubmit(a);
                IEnumerable<person> query = from p in tble
                                            where p.id == 5
                                            select p;

                foreach (person e in query) { Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", e.id, e.name); }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to test Linq-to-SQL.

The error is:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>   Additional information: The type 'dbtst.person' is not mapped as a Table.

Comment: Well it's absolutely right - there's nothing to map the `person` class to a database table. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384396.aspx (I'd also strongly encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First chance error means there is some problem in the code.

Try replacing below piece of code

```
 Table<person> tble = db.GetTable<person>();

 person a = new person();
 a.id = 5;
 tble.InsertOnSubmit(a);
 person b = new person();
 a.id = 6;
 tble.InsertOnSubmit(a);
```

with following piece of code:

```
 person a = new person();
 a.id = 5;
 person b = new person();
 b.id = 6;
 db.persons.InsertOnSubmit(a);
 db.persons.InsertOnSubmit(b);
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Wondering how did you get a reference to db.persons ?